What is the name, or historical illustration, for the military strategy of biding time?
What would be a historical term, or a historical episode, to
illustrate the following war strategy?  The scenario is that while
side X is attacking, side Y is adopting the strategy of biding its
time, apparently at a high cost to itself, so as to get side X fully
to expose its offensive capabilities?
Deng Xiaoping advocated the strategy of biding the time, but the purpose seems to have been more to conceal one's own strength than cause the opponents to expose their capabilities.
A user helpfully suggested to explore the dictum attributed to Napoleon:

"Never interrupt your enemy when he is making a mistake."

Looking this up on the web, I found an article that seems to argue that the Russians lured the Germans into Stalingrad (in accordance with Napoleon's dictum).  This is close though not identical to what I am asking.
Question. Are there examples from an earlier period, perhaps an even more pertinent example from Napoleon's period?
Note. According to recent media reports, the rebels in Syria had plans ready at least six months ago (and informed Turkey about them).  If there is any indication that they were waiting to gauge Assad's ability to rebuff their attack, that might be an example of the type I am looking for.

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s). At a minimum, all questions should explain why Wikipedia is insufficient.

wu wei ? Fabian  Are you convinced that there is a name for such a strategy? How will anyone know if the answer is provided?  is there an Authoritative answer or is this an opinion based question?

I'm beginning to suspect that the answer is "biding time".

Isn't a Fabian strategy more about avoiding decisive battles (that one could lose), be they offensive or defensive?

@ItalianPhilosopher, I was looking for something more along the lines of waiting for side X to expose their capabilities; to take a modern example, before proceeding with a counterattack, side Y may be interested in obtaining evidence whether side X possess a certain type of offensive drone; waiting to obtain such intelligence may help side Y choose the most effective course of action.  Just to give a wild example.

Well, I don't know if there is any term for it, but you often hear of battles, or offensives, where side A doesn't commit much and is trying to sound out what B is up to with minimal forces of their own.  It's usually pretty clear in the context and I don't know that it needs, or has, a specialized word.  "screening force", "reconnaissance" etc..., are adjacent terms.  Often it is less about knowing the enemy unit types - like your drone types - than their number and precise location.  Might be better asked @ SE.English.

"you often hear of battles" : What would be a well-known historical example?  This is pretty much what I am looking for (not necessarily a specific term in English).  @ItalianPhilosopher

Maybe look into Jeb Stuart's role in supporting Lee's strategies during the US Civil War?  But they're a dime a dozen:  competent commanders will often avoid early commitment if they are unsure where their enemy is massed.

"Never interrupt your enemy when he is making a mistake" - Napoleon

@RLeonard, That sounds promising.  Did Napoleon have a particular battle in mind that he may have referred to in this comment?  Do you have a source for this?

Perhaps the Battle of Austerlitz?

I admire the concern for precision at this SE. @MCW

@MCW, I don't know which episode Napoleon himself was referring to.  As far as the example I mentioned, it is not from Napoleon's period but rather from the 20th century.

an extreme example of this might be the "phony war" just around the start of WW2 in Europe, where ALL SIDES tried to outstare the other.

@jwenting, this sounds intriguing.  I am not too familiar with the details of that particular story.  I was taught history in the Soviet Union (that particular perspective probably disagrees with the one you mention), and since then went into mostly mathematics rather than history :-)  Could you elaborate?  Feel free to post an answer.

There's a decent article about it on wikipedia

@jwenting, I am sure there are many articles about WW2 at wiki.  Could you possibly specify which page, and which subsection, you may be referring to?

@MikhailKatz your Syrian sample a clear sample of Fabian's strategy below in the asnwer: to let the enemy do as he want, keep a low profile and wait for the right time/chance to hit

I have been reflecting on your exact choice of words: " ...so as to get side X fully to expose its offensive capabilities". Your comments suggest that you actually mean the word "expose" as in "reveal" as in those capabilities have been unknown to Y up until now. You are not likely to find a matching term. No commander of Y of note would willing allow a prolonged attack unless he was sure that he keep up the defense at an acceptable cost. This requires a good estimate of the attacker X's capabilities. This is exactly the situation at Stalingrad and later at Kursk.

@Carl, indeed I used "expose" in the sense of "reveal". I don't think the scenario is that far-fetched. For example, Azerbaidzhan won the war in Nagorno-Karabach because they had an advanced type of drone. I imagine they made very sure Armenia had no defense against that type of weapon before they went on the attack. Disclaimer: I side with neither side in that particular conflict. I was hoping that Chandler's book that you recommended might have some pertinent examples, but I am hesitant to register at the Internet Archive.  If you have any other way of getting it to me I would appreciate it.

Alas, I do not have a electronic copy of the book. I believe that I understand your question. I am afraid that I know of no such term and my best approximation remains "Attack from a Defensive Position".  Had you meant "commit" as in "commit all reserves" instead of "reveal", then it would been a perfect match, but you didn't and so it isn't.

@CarlChristian, thanks for your comment.  I did mean "reveal" as in "expose".  Perhaps there is no name but I am still hoping for a historical illustration of this kind of strategy...

What you describe is a close match to one of the seven classical maneuvers of warfare listed in David G. Chandler's book "The Art of Warfare on Land".
Chandler is recognized as an authority on military history, specializing in the Napoleonic era.
The maneuvers are:

Penetration of the Centre
Envelopment of a Single Flank
Envelopment of Both Flanks
The Feigned Withdrawal
Attack in Oblique Order
Attack from a Defensive Position
The Indirect Approach

Chandler list several examples and variations of each maneuver. Here the relevant maneuver is number 6: Attack from a Defensive Position. I shall quote Chandler ad verbatim:

Napoleon once wrote: "The whole art of war consists in a well-reasoned
and extremely circumspect defensive, followed by a rapid and audacious
attack." In adapting this method, an army prepares a strong sanctuary
or defensive position, onto which it proceeds to lure the enemy. When
the enemy has exhausted his energy in a useless attack against the
perimeter, the garrison sallies forth to accomplish his defeat.
Clearly this manoeuvre is often associated with one described
previously, but it is open to many variations.

Chandler goes on to list several examples including:

A refined example of a third variation was Wellington's use of the
secretly prepared Lines of Torres Vedras in Portugal to confound
Marshal Masséna. After luring Masséna on to the lines by a lengthy
retreat, Wellington turned at bay within a triple line of
impregnable positions, and used scorched earth and guerilla tactics to
starve and harass his foe before issuing forth against a retreating
opponent.

Chandler's examples from WWII are the Battle of Kohima-Imphal as well as the Battle of Stalingrad.

David Chandler
"The Art of Warfare on Land"
Printed in Great Britain by Jarrold & Sons Ltd. Norwich 1974
ISBN 0 600 30137 0

Copy at the Internet Archive

Good to know about Chandler's book, thanks.

Unfortunately I was only able to find a chapter by the same name by Chandler, dating from 1970.  Apparently he expanded it into a book 4 years later.

@MikhailKatz I have added a link to an electronic copy of the book at the "Internet Archive". If you make an account there, then you will be able to borrow the book and read it online.

It has a name! Though perhaps it shouldn't.
This strategy has been referred to as the Fabian strategy for Quintus Fabius Maximus Verrucosus, surnamed "the delayer" for his association with the strategy.
I say that perhaps it shouldn't have a name because the strategy really arises from the conditions of battle. If you are facing an attacker with long supply lines AND you have the ability to give up land/materiel/troops in order to lengthen those supply lines AND lengthening those lines will press your opponent into conceding things they don't want to, THEN the strategy works. As some commenters have noted, this is less a "strategy" than a contingent response to what the battle looks like.

It is also the plot and name of an episode of 30 Rock, which is how I was able to remember the name and answer the question.


Good try but as mentioned in the comments, "Fabian strategy more about avoiding decisive battles".

This is the answer to your question. There isn't an answer with the parameters you are setting.

You may be right, but let's wait and see.

@MikhailKatz You’ll see this strategy fade away as it becomes more difficult to sustain an army on “the land” alone. Folks are quoting Napoleon to you but he’s probably the last famous canonical recipient of the business end of this strategy as Russia burned towns before he could loot them. Germany stalled in the same place later but not really under the weight of what you are asking about.

Adam, the strategy might fade away, but historical examples (from Napoleon's period or earlier) would also be of interest.

What I mean is not that the strategy is no longer important or worth talking about, but that the closer to the present day when armies run on gasoline and not stomachs you get, the fewer examples you'll see of this.

Your question is not really clear:

in the beginning you ask for definition
in the end you ask for sample (which is against guidelines)

I will try to answer anyway:
The definition
The definition you're looking for may be "Attrition Warfare":

Attrition warfare is a military strategy consisting of belligerent
attempts to win a war by wearing down the enemy to the point of
collapse through continuous losses in personnel, materiel and morale.

even though the citation from "Attrition warfare against Napoleon" is even more relevant to your definition:

Attrition warfare represents an attempt to grind down an opponent's
ability to make war by destroying their military resources by any
means possible, including scorched earth, people's war, guerrilla
warfare and all kind of battles apart from a decisive battle.

(note: the source book is the same for both pages)
The samples

first sample (oldest):

Scythian campaign of Darius I:

Darius inflicted widespread damage on the Scythians and their allies,
weakened the prestige of the Royal Scythians especially, and upset the
balance of power among the various peoples of the region. However, he
suffered very heavy losses and did not fulfill the tasks set for the
campaign. He failed to bring the Scythians to battle, he was unable to
secure any territorial gains and he did not even complete the building
of the forts at what could have been a frontier. The campaign was
little more than an expensive stalemate


Second sample (Napoleon era):

This tactics has been widely used against Napoleon (and not only by Russia)

Other sample(s)
I was thinking of other sample that may fit your question - even if there is no definition of the strategy:

Historical ones:

the Battle of Gaugamela, in which Alexander caused an opening in the flank of Darius letting their forces in:

As the Persians advanced farther and farther to the Greek flanks in
their attack, Alexander slowly filtered in his rear guard. He
disengaged his Companions and prepared for the decisive attack. Behind
them were the guard's brigade along with any phalanx battalions he
could withdraw from the battle


Avoidance of a decisive battle seems also known under the name "Fabian strategy".

I would probably not include Alesia because the Romans besiege the town more than anything, but I would say the Vietnam war is a great example, with daily skirmishes tearing down morale and ressources of the ennemy.

@MikhailKatz I don't understand your requirements, in your question is the behavior of the attacking part, but nothing about the defensive one. To not engage in decisive battle is a legitimate strategy under your premise "Never interrupt your enemy when he is making a mistake"

@OldPadawan I revised the answer - you're right. It was in the mind of Gauls to have the Romans come and be taken between two armies

Dan, that's Napoleon's premise, not mine.  My question is about something more specific than the Fabian strategy: namely, the defending side waiting not merely adopting a waiting tactic, but waiting for the attackers to reveal which capabilities they have, before the defenders proceeding to counterattack.  To give an example in the Syrian context: if the rebels waited with their counterattack with the intention of determining whether Assad has capabilities to defend against their drones, that would be the kind of example the question is looking for.

@MikhailKatz in Syria happened the perfect sample of Fabian tactics: avoid confrontation till you see a window of opportunity. Fabian tactics is not “just do nothing”, but “wait till the right time”

@DanM, True, but my question is more specific than the Fabian tactic, as I explained.

Your question is very unclear, confusing, and confused.
But maybe something like what you're looking for is this:
Empty Fort Strategy.
Kissinger's description (from On China, 2011):

One of the classic tales of the Chinese strategic tradition was that of Zhuge Liang’s “Empty City Stratagem” from The Romance of the Three Kingdoms. In it, a commander notices an approaching army far superior to his own. Since resistance guarantees destruction, and surrender would bring about loss of control over the future, the commander opts for a stratagem. He opens the gates of his city, places himself there in a posture of repose, playing a lute, and behind him shows normal life without any sign of panic or concern. The general of the invading army interprets this sangfroid as a sign of the existence of hidden reserves, stops his advance, and withdraws.

